# ¿Cómo reutilizar una SQL si no se pasa uno de los 2 parámetros?

Tags: php, mysql, array, base-de-datos, pdo

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo reutilizar un SQL dentro de una función, debo decir que hago uso de PDO de MYSQL.
Esta sería mi función.

```
function todos_datos_usuarios_de_oferta($id_oferta, $id_usuario = '')
{$sql = "SELECT oferta, usuario FROM MY_TABLE WHERE oferta = :id_oferta"}
```

Como les dije estoy usando PDO así que me toca hacer lo siguiente para que la SQL se ejecute

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$parametro = array(':id_oferta' => $id_oferta); //Agrego los parámetros que necesito
$stmt->execute($parametro); // Ejecuto la SQL junto con los parametros.
```

Listo, mi idea es la siguiente, cómo puedo hacer con esta estructura si a mi función **todos_datos_usuarios_de_oferta** le llega un valor diferente de vacío al parámetro de id_usuario, a este se le agregue a la SQL el operador

```
AND usuario = :id_usuario
```

y obviamente en la variable `$parametro` se le debe agregar al array ese valor de la siguiente forma

```
$parametro[':id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
```

Entonces lo que necesitaría es lo siguiente, que si a la función se le pasa un valor a la variable `$id_usuario`, este haga que la SQL quede así.

```
SELECT oferta, usuario FROM MY_TABLE WHERE oferta = :id_oferta AND usuario = :id_usuario
```

Si no le llega un valor a la variable `$id_usuario`, entonces que la SQL quede igual como la tengo inicialmente.

Muchas Gracias por ayudarme, espero que me hayan entendido, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function todos_datos_usuarios_de_oferta($id_oferta, $id_usuario = '')
{
    $complemento = '';
    $parametros = array(':id_oferta' => $id_oferta);
    if ($id_usuario != '') {
        $complemento .= "AND id_usuario_en_rel_oferta = :id_usuario";
        $parametros[':id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id_usuario_en_rel_oferta, id_oferta_en_rel_oferta
            WHERE id_oferta_en_rel_oferta = :id_oferta {$complemento} ";
    //PREPARAMOS LA SQL
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    //EJECUTAMOS LA SENTENCIA PASANDOLE LA VARIABLE DE PARAMETROS
    $stmt->execute($parametros);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
} // FIN DE LA FUNCION
```

Cómo podemos ver en esta función definimos primeramente la variable `$complemento` vacía y la variable `$parametros` va a contener un Array del dato que llegue a la variable `$id_oferta` esta variable si o si va a ser pasada a la función, como siguiente preguntamos si la variable `$id_usuario` es diferente a vacía osea que lleva algún dato, entonces a la variable `$complemento` le asignamos un string de la sentencia SQL y por último a la variable `$parametros` se le agrega una segunda posición al array de clave :id_usuario.

Esta fue mi solución, espero que alguna otra persona necesite de esta ayuda o pueda mejorar la lógica a como yo la tengo, de antemano le agradezco al usuario @Fergush por la ayuda, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

¿Te valdría esto?

```
$slice = 'AND usuario = :id_usuario'
{$sql = "SELECT oferta, usuario FROM MY_TABLE WHERE oferta = :id_oferta ".$slice}
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que $sql es simplemente un string, concatenale otro string con el AND cuando lo necesites y ya está :D

Comment: Hola amigo, sí eso estoy tratando de hacer, pero la salida del SQL no me agarra el valor que viene del $id_usuario, te voy a pegar lo que tengo hasta ahora del codigo

Comment: https://gist.github.com/LearningTools/437228627326ef35148812bfbf3c7334

Comment: Te comparto este gist para que veas como tengo el codigo

Comment: Y en la salida del SQL me agrega el AND id_usuario efectivamente, pero no le pasa el parametro, llega de la siguiente forma: AND id_usuario_en_rel_oferta = :id_usuario (Debería el :id_usuario ser reemplazado por el valor que trae la variable de $id_usuario)

Comment: Hola amigo, creo que ya lo pude resolver. Solo tuve que colocar el array del parámetro arriba del condicional
$complemento = '';
  $parametros = array(':id_oferta' => $id_oferta);
  if ($id_usuario != '') {
   $complemento .= "AND id_usuario_en_rel_oferta = :id_usuario";
   $parametros[':id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
  }

Comment: Si finalmente has conseguido solucionarlo, pon una respuesta con la solución, para usuario que puedan tener el mismo problema :D